# How to use an apikey when parsing a website with java?

Tags: java, api, httpurlconnection, api-key

So in general I'm tring to make a timetable app, but first trying to learn to parse the data from the system's api. I've been given a apikey from the systems admin of my school but the API is vague and I don't understand it. I'm trying to use HttpURLConnection.

Here's the API tutorial regarding the apikey and some variable to use commands which I don't get either

> apikey This is a kind of password for accessing Edupage API for a
>   school’s Edupage page. One school (and one Edupage web page) can have
>   multiple API keys. It is possible to configure access rights for every
>   API key individually, so school can give one API key to company
>   providing attendance system (with postbeeps right) and other to
>   company providing digital signages (with getdailyplan right). 
>   cmd This
>   parameter specifies API command. Commands are listed later in a
>   separate chapter.

I see the commands it refers to at cmd but again, dont know how to use the correct syntax.

So far I have the code

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String apikey = myapikey;
        String apiurl = url;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(apiurl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");


        } catch (MalformedURLException ex){
            return;
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Could anybody please help me?

Comment: Well, there's not much to go off of here, but seeing as they're mentioning "parameter"s is it possible you're expected to pass the apikey in the URL you request as a GET parameter? eg: https://api.acme.example.com/some_api/users/get?apiKey=abc123

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation page I found via google](http://www.help.edupage.org/text.php?id=1242&lang=gr) gives a link with further technical specifications available [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1D6FtHZSIeB7PvI6NCgpclCXq8lgZag-jK4zNgcinRcI/edit?usp=sharing)

Per this documentation, you can pass the cmd or apiKey variables either via a POST parameter or a GET parameter (in the query string)

> Communication overview
>   Communication is done through simple HTTP
>   requests. These requests can be either GET or POST requests and all
>   parameters can be passed in both ways (in URL query string or in POST
>   content or any combination of both). Note: There is a limit on size of
>   URL in the web server, so for parameters that can be very long it is
>   recommended to send them as POST.

the approach you use is going to depend on what api you're using and personal preference, but there are plenty of tutorials online for submitting POST requests via java HTTPUrlConnection or other things like commons HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of way to send data in httpurlconnection.Its up to you how you want to send data.

you are using get method so you can pass apikey in header.

Like

```
connection.setRequestProperty("apikey", apikey)
```

If you are making post request then  you can open output stream on connection and then write your apikey in there.

```
var outputStream = conn.outputStream
        outputStream.write(apikey.toByteArray())
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
```